# Fetching authorized Google Search Console user websites?

Tags: next.js, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-search-console, google-search-api

I'm making a SAAS that will index articles and pages faster using Google Search Console API. I have made the authoisation with Next-Auth since I'm using NextJS. The user logs in with their google account. When I console log their session, I'm only getting their email and name. Nothing else, is this normal?

**I want to list their websites that are connected to Google Search Console.**

Some info:

Page where I will list the websites:

´´´

```
import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth'
import React from 'react'
import { options } from '../api/auth/[...nextauth]/options'
const MyWebsitesPage = async () => {

const session = await getServerSession(options)

console.log("session", session)

return (
    <div className='container max-w-6xl mx-auto pl-5 pr-5'>

    </div>
)
}
```

´´´

My auth options page:

```
import type { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth'
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

export const options: NextAuthOptions = {
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string
        })
    ]
}
```

Comment: Despite the question mark, "Fetching authorized Google Search Console user websites?" isn't a question.  What are you asking? How long it would take for the API call to complete?

Comment: Hi @StephenOstermiller, Im making a small saas that will utilize Google Search Console's API to help users get their websites indexed faster on Google. But first I will need access to their autorized GSC websites and sitemaps. I thought I could get access to that when making the user login with their connected google account, but maybe not.

The api call finished almost directly. You can see more here: https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v1/api_reference_index

Comment: So your question is how to get access to a client's Google Search Console API?  Do you have a place for the client to enter API keys?

Comment: I dont think I have to do that. Check out tagparrot (dot) com, It's something like what I want to do. They only need me to login with my google account and then they can fetch my verified websites and sitemaps from GSC. @StephenOstermiller